# How much extra carpet do installers need?

Tags: installation, carpet

Replacing the carpet in our hallway.

I measured the majority of the hallway to be 162 sq. ft. And the remaining small patches of carpet to be 10 sq. ft. and 8 sq. ft.

180 Sq ft.  = 20 Sq. Yards.

**Yet** the estimate we got was for 30 Sq. Yards???

Can anyone explain why so much extra sq yardage is needed?

Am I missing something or am I getting hosed?

[image]

Comment: Carpet comes on a roll with a standard width.  Given that and minimizing seams wherever possible (seams don’t wear nearly as well).  The length they must cut from the roll, and that standard width determine how much is needed.

Comment: And if there's, say, a small closet, the portion of the roll adjacent to the closet is often unusable due to size or orientation. A diagram of your hallway might help clarify the 50% overage.

Comment: @tyson Updated question

Comment: Carpet rolls are different widths, we’d need to know that—common roll width are 12’, 13’6”, and 15’.  The 8sq ft area uses at least 16sq ft of carpet, actually more again depending on roll width.  While sq ft calculations are somewhat helpful, what we really need are dimensions of the areas AND the width of the roll you are interested in, then we can fully explain how much you should need.  Another area of carpet laying that can cause waste, is pattern matching on seams.

Comment: There is no pattern. It's 1 color. The hallway is basically a simple rectangle. I've done the math in my head a few times. If i were to install the carpet. I don't see how i could possibly justify 50% more carpet.

Comment: Example: the 8sq ft area is obviously 4x4.  But if carpet for that area needs to be seamed on and the width of the roll is 12 then that area will use 12x4 or 48sqft.  Out of that waste they can probably get the roughly 3x3 closet, but until we know dimensions and roll width we can’t even see whether those two small areas need to be seemed on.  You are buying a Length of carpet that is a specific width. That’s why DIMENSIONS and not square footages are needed to calculate this.

Comment: How wide is the hallway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carpet isn't paint.  You can't infinitely cut and splice carpet and put a bunch of seams in it, and expect to have a surface that will wear well.

So you can't understand the problem until you know the dimensions of each space and also the dimensions of the supplied carpet.

It's just like if you buy cloth to make a pair of pants, and your waist is 44 inches, so each panel of the pants need to be about 13" wide, except the cloth you like comes in 40 inch wide bolts. You will end up wasting almost half the cloth. That's just how cutting and fitting works.

The installers are probably planning to run the carpet linearly down the hall so there are no seams in the hall, then do the side rooms with remnants if they are not able to fit it direct.